# How to add Relationship of Factories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two Models

> Artist
>
> Album

I am trying to write a Factory to seed the databse like this

```
$factory->define(App\Artist::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'artist_name' => $faker->name($gender = null|'male'|'female'),
        'followers'    => $faker->randomDigitNotNull(),
        'artist_image'=>$faker->imageUrl($width = 256, $height = 256), 
        'artist_title' =>$faker->word(4),
        'artist_address' =>$faker->address(),
        'artist_phone' =>$faker->phoneNumber(),
        'artist_fb' =>$faker->sentence(4),
        'artist_description' => $faker->paragraph()
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Album::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
    'album_name' => $faker->company(),
    'album_art' => $faker->imageUrl($width = 263, $height = 292),
    'album_description' => $faker->paragraph($nbSentences = 3, $variableNbSentences = true),
    'album_mainart' => $faker->imageUrl($width = 1140, $height = 1140),  
    'album_soundcloud' => $faker->company(),
    'album_youtube' => $faker->company(),
    'artist_id' => factory(App\Artist::class)->create()->id,
    ];
});
```

and In DatabaseSeeder.php I have like this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
         Model::unguard();
         //DB::table('artists');
       // factory(App\Artist::class, 50)->create();

        factory(App\Artist::class, 10)
           ->create()
           ->each(function($u) {
                $u->posts()->save(factory(App\Album::class)->make());
            });

          Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

after executing

`php artisan db:seed`

**ERROR**

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::posts()

Any Idea how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The posts() method should not be defined in your Artist model. You should have a albums() method. Try this:

```
factory(App\Artist::class, 10)
           ->create()
           ->each(function($u) {
                $u->albums()->save(factory(App\Album::class)->make());
            });
```

And review your Artist model.